# How to execute different implementation of a method of a generic struct based on the generic type?

Tags: swift

I have a generic struct. I have added a method to the struct in an extension as follows-

```swift
struct CustomStruct<T> {
    let data: T?
}
extension CustomStruct {
    func method1() {
    }
}
```

When the type of the `T` is `String`, I would like the `method1` to perform different action.
I tried adding another extension with generic type constraint as follows-

```swift
extension CustomStruct where T == String {
    func method1() {
        print("method1 for string called")
    }
}
```

However, the above method is not called when following code is executed.

```swift
let struct1 = CustomStruct<String>(data: "something")
struct1.method1()
```

Can anyone point out how to solve this issue?

Edit- The above code does not point out the issue that I am having as noted by @scriptable and @matt. The below code points out the issue that I am having

```swift
struct CustomStruct<T> {
    let data: T?
}
extension CustomStruct {
    func method1() {
        print("method1 for all type called")
    }
}
extension CustomStruct where T == String {
    func method1() {
        print("method1 for string called")
    }
}

func callMethod1<T>(customStruct: CustomStruct<T>) {
    customStruct.method1()
}

let struct1 = CustomStruct<String>(data: "something")

callMethod1(customStruct: struct1)
```

Comment: What swift version are you using? I just ran your code in a playground and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can't be reproduced from the example you gave. I'm going to assume that you are having a more complicated issue, that you tried to boil it down for this question, and that you boiled it down incorrectly. I'm going to guess that what you're actually seeing is something like this:

```
struct CustomStruct<T> {
    let data: T?
    func method1() {
        print("original method1")
    }
    func method2() {
        method1()
    }
}
extension CustomStruct where T == String {
    func method1() {
        print("method1 for string called")
    }
}
let struct1 = CustomStruct(data: "something")
struct1.method1() // method1 for string called
struct1.method2() // original method1
```

As you can see, if we call `method1` directly, ourselves, we pass through the extension. (That's why the issue can't be reproduced from the example you gave.) But if we call `method2`, which calls `method1`, we get the original `method1`, not the one belonging to the extension.

Is that the real issue?

If so, you may be experiencing a common misconception, in which you are attempting to use a `where` clause to enable some sort of type-based dispatch. That's wrong, and is not what a `where` clause is for. As Jordan Rose puts it [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10549):

> In Swift, the function that gets called is chosen at the place where the call is made.

The way to get type-based dispatch (as he goes on to say) is through standard approaches like overriding (polymorphism) and overloading (distinct method signatures). Or you can of course examine the type yourself and make a decision in real time.

To put it another way: you can't use an extension to perform a method override. But that's exactly what you're attempting to do. You can't use where clauses to turn a struct into a class (dynamic dispatch), or to do the job of overloading.

Comment: I can't give any further positive suggestion without knowing more about the real original situation. Based on what you've actually shown, I'd say this is a bad use of a generic (i.e. this is a job for overloading, not a generic), but perhaps there's some broader reason for using a generic that you haven't told us about.

Comment: To put it another way: any time you find yourself type-checking inside a generic, that's a big bad smell and you should probably back away from the generic.

Comment: I agree with @matt ... Your generic types should have all the information it needs to do its work (this can be achieved by passing parameters into the methods, by initializers or limiting the generic to a specific bound)